# How to prevent infinite loop caused of router.push inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have `users` state inside my React component. If there is new user added I want to update the URL and add to query params new information about the amount of users.
The problem is `push` with new query param is called in infinite loop because `users` is new array each time.

How to prevent this infinite loop?
Two important things: I use React 18 and I don't want to fire `push` inside `addUser` function.

```
export default function Home() {
  const {push} = useRouter();
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const addUser = useCallback(() => {
    setUsers([...users, `Tommy-${Math.random()}`]);
  }, [users]);

  useEffect(() => {
    push({
      pathname: "/",
      query: {
        amount: users.length,
      },
    });
  }, [users, push]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={addUser}>Add user</button>
        <ul>
          {users.map((user) => (
            <li key={user}>{user}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why you do not want to trigger that inside addUser? Just curious.
Maybe you can add an early return inside the useEffect if users.length is the same.

Comment: @maxpsz This is simplified example. In real application `push` lives in other function `createQueryParamsAndPush()` and generates query params based on `users` state.  I could fire it like this: `createQueryParamsAndPush(users)` inside `addUser` but that would require me to pass `users` into that function which I don't want to (because the state lives in the same scope so it feels stupid to pass it like this).
And I cannot compare users.length because it is more complicated in real world and length can be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is reference to `push` that you have added in the `useEffect` dependencies is changing, hence the infinite rerender.

My suggestion: Just remove the `push` from dependencies, the function is not dependent on the current state of `users` anyways.

Also I did a quick search and found [this issues](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18127) on `github`, discussing the issue fully, to state some of the solutions:

- #### If you want to use the new `Layouts RFC`:

> This is fixed in the new router that is part of the app directory. We've changed the router in pages to be a stable reference a few months ago but it broke many existing applications so instead we've focused on making the new router have the right behavior as it'll become the recommended way to build Next.js applications when it's stable. The new router has other benefits like being built on top of React transitions and is concurrent rendering compatible.

- #### If the reason for adding `push` in the dependencies is `ESlint` there's this workaround:

> `Router` can be used in `useEffect` only or outside of the React lifecycles. I understand this is not the best solution but I prefer to use it over `eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

```
import Router from 'next/router'

useEffect(() => {
    Router.push({
      pathname: "/",
      query: {
        amount: users.length,
      },
    });
}, [users])
```

Comment: You are right, `push` was the issue, I didn't think of that because libraries usually return stable references