# Router.push infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, url, router

Need help with inserting parameters into the url line.

I have now implemented this `window.history.pushState`.

But the problem is that when you press back in the browser, the url changes to the previous one, but the transition does not occur. I think in order for there to be a transition, you need to do it through the useRouter hook from next.

The problem is that when I use it in useEffect, instead of `window.history.pushState (router.push(?entity=${activeTab});)` , the page begins infinite loop. Has anyone encountered this? I spent a lot of time on this, I would be very grateful for your help.

I tried to solve the problem using these methods, but it didn’t help=(
[How to prevent infinite loop caused of router.push inside useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75842524/how-to-prevent-infinite-loop-caused-of-router-push-inside-useeffect)
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18127

```
  const Search: FC = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const [term, setTerm] = useState<string>(searchParams.get('term') || '');
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState<string>(
    searchParams.get('entity') || 'beers'
  );

  const tabsItems = [
    { value: 'beers', option: 'Beers' },
    { value: 'breweries', option: 'Breweries' },
    { value: 'users', option: 'Users' },
    { value: 'bars', option: 'Bars' },
    { value: 'celebrities', option: 'Celebrities' },
  ];

  const onTabChange = (tab: ITab) => {
    setActiveTab(tab.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.history.pushState(
      null,
      '',
      `?entity=${activeTab}`
    );
  }, [activeTab, term]);

  return (
    <section>
      <Tabs
        items={tabsItems}
        activeTab={activeTab}
        onChange={onTabChange}
        className={styles.tabs}
        tabClassName={styles.tab}
        activeClassName={styles.active}
      />

      <Actions term={term} setTerm={setTerm} />

      {activeTab === 'beers' && <Beers term={term} />}
      {activeTab === 'breweries' && <Breweries term={term} />}
      {activeTab === 'users' && <Users term={term} />}
      {activeTab === 'bars' && <div>Bars Bars</div>}
      {activeTab === 'celebrities' && <div>Сelebrities Сelebrities</div>}
    </section>
  );
};

export default Search;
```